# Tkinter GUI used to work, but now I have a empty window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

I have a code that used to work just fine.
Today, I played with py2exe with an other code, but since then, all I have from my code is en empty window.
I don't know if those two things are related, but thats all I can find to explain.

Does someone have an idea ?
I'm kind of lost.

thanks for your help

Here's my code :

```
# coding=UTF-8
import socket
import pickle
from Tkinter import *
from functools import partial
#import Image, ImageTk

hote = "127.0.0.1"
port = 443

print("Tentative de connection avec le serveur")
ok = False
while(not ok):
    try:
        connexion_avec_serveur = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        connexion_avec_serveur.connect((hote, port))
        print("Connexion etablie avec le serveur sur le port {}".format(port))
        ok = True
    except:
        pass


class Interface(Frame):    
    def __init__(self, fenetre, **kwargs):
        fenetre.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.deco)
        Frame.__init__(self, fenetre, width=1024, height=900, **kwargs)

        #Banner :
        #img = Image.open("include/img/banner.png")
        #banner = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        #bannerLabel = Label(image=banner)
        #bannerLabel.grid(row=1, column=1)
        #bannerLabel.image = banner

        self.nb_clic = 0

        self.bouton_quitter = Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.deco)
        self.bouton_quitter.grid(row=32, column=1)


        self.torrentsName  = []
        self.torrentsDesc  = []
        self.torrentsDate  = []
        self.torrentsRatio = []
        self.torrentsGoTo  = []
        self.torrentsDown  = []

        self.configFenetre()

        self.boutonPrev = Button(self, text="precedents", state=DISABLED)
        self.boutonPrev.grid(row=32, column=2)
        self.boutonSuiv = Button(self, text="Suivants", state=DISABLED)
        self.boutonSuiv.grid(row=32, column=3)

        # Creation de nos widgets        
        self.bouton_ListeTorrents = Button(self, text="Liste des torrents", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getTorrents", None))
        self.bouton_ListeTorrents.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.bouton_ListeSeries = Button(self, text="Liste des Series", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getSpeTorrents", "series"))
        self.bouton_ListeSeries.grid(row=3, column=1)

        self.bouton_ListeFilms = Button(self, text="Liste des Films", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getSpeTorrents", "films"))
        self.bouton_ListeFilms.grid(row=4, column=1)

        self.bouton_ListeLivres = Button(self, text="Liste des Livres", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getSpeTorrents", "livres"))
        self.bouton_ListeLivres.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.bouton_ListeJeux = Button(self, text="Liste des Jeux", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getSpeTorrents", "jeux"))
        self.bouton_ListeJeux.grid(row=6, column=1)

        self.bouton_ListeMusiques = Button(self, text="Liste des Musiques", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getSpeTorrents", "musiques"))
        self.bouton_ListeMusiques.grid(row=7, column=1)

        self.bouton_ListeDivers = Button(self, text="Liste des torrents Divers", command= lambda: self.sendCmd("getSpeTorrents", "divers"))
        self.bouton_ListeDivers.grid(row=8, column=1)


    def configFenetre(self):
        i = 0

        self.torrentsName.append(Label(self, text="Nom du torrent"))
        self.torrentsName[0].grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.torrentsDesc.append(Label(self, text="Type de fichier"))
        self.torrentsDesc[0].grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.torrentsDate.append(Label(self, text="Date ajout"))
        self.torrentsDate[0].grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.torrentsRatio.append(Label(self, text="Ratio"))
        self.torrentsRatio[0].grid(row=1, column=5)
        self.torrentsGoTo.append(Label(self, text="Voir la page"))
        self.torrentsGoTo[0].grid(row=1, column=6)
        self.torrentsDown.append(Label(self, text="Telecharger"))
        self.torrentsDown[0].grid(row=1, column=7)
        while i< 30:
            self.torrentsName.append(Label(self, text="          "))
            self.torrentsName[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=2)
            self.torrentsDesc.append(Label(self, text="          "))
            self.torrentsDesc[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=3)
            self.torrentsDate.append(Label(self, text="          "))
            self.torrentsDate[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=4)
            self.torrentsRatio.append(Label(self, text="          "))
            self.torrentsRatio[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=5)
            self.torrentsGoTo.append(Button(self, text="Voir", state=DISABLED))
            self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=6)
            self.torrentsDown.append(Button(self, text="DL", state=DISABLED))
            self.torrentsDown[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=7)
            i+=1

    def sendCmd(self, cmd, args):
        msg_a_envoyer = b""
        if(args == None):
            msg_a_envoyer = cmd
        else:
            msg_a_envoyer = cmd
            msg_a_envoyer += " "
            msg_a_envoyer += args

        msg_a_envoyer = msg_a_envoyer.encode()
        connexion_avec_serveur.send(msg_a_envoyer)
        self.resceive()

    def resceive(self):
        msg_recu = b""
        chaine =b""
        while(not(b"<EOT>" in msg_recu)):
            msg_recu = connexion_avec_serveur.recv(1024)
            if(msg_recu != b"<EOT>"):
                chaine += msg_recu

        if(b"<EOT>" in msg_recu):
            chaine.replace(b"<EOT>", b"")
            dechifre = pickle.loads(chaine)
            self.dealString(dechifre, 0)

    def deleteLabels(self, liste):
        for label in liste:
            label.grid_remove()

    def getRatioColor(self, nb):
        if(nb == (-1)):
            return self.cget('bg')
        if(nb < 1):
            return '#FF0000'
        if(nb >= 1 and nb < 2):
            return '#FF8000'
        if(nb >= 2):
            return '#3ADF00'

    def getBackgroundColor(self, i):
        if(i%2 == 0):
            return '#E0F8E0'
        if(i%2 == 1):
            return '#CEE3F6'
        if(i == -1):
            return self.cget('bg')


    def dealString(self, chaine, page):
        nbPage = 30
        i=0
        j = (page*nbPage)
        nbSplit = len(chaine)


        #On ajoute les entetes
        self.torrentsName.append(Label(self, text="Nom du torrent"))
        self.torrentsName[0].grid(row=1, column=2)
        self.torrentsDesc.append(Label(self, text="Type de fichier"))
        self.torrentsDesc[0].grid(row=1, column=3)
        self.torrentsDate.append(Label(self, text="Date ajout"))
        self.torrentsDate[0].grid(row=1, column=4)
        self.torrentsRatio.append(Label(self, text="Ratio"))
        self.torrentsRatio[0].grid(row=1, column=5)

        #On ajoutel les torrents
        while(j<nbSplit and (j<((page*nbPage)+nbPage))):

            self.torrentsName[i+1].config(text=chaine[j][0], background=self.getBackgroundColor(i+1))
            self.torrentsName[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=2)

            self.torrentsDesc[i+1].config(text=chaine[j][1], background=self.getBackgroundColor(i+1))
            self.torrentsDesc[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=3)

            self.torrentsDate[i+1].config(text=chaine[j][2], background=self.getBackgroundColor(i+1))
            self.torrentsDate[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=4)

            self.torrentsRatio[i+1].config(text=round(chaine[j][3], 2), background=self.getRatioColor(chaine[j][3]))
            self.torrentsRatio[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=5)

            if(chaine[j][5] == True):
                fVoir = partial(self.sendCmd, "getSpeTorrents", chaine[j][6])
                self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].config(text="Voir", state=NORMAL, command = fVoir)
                self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=6)
            else:
                self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].config(text="Voir", state=DISABLED)
                self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=6)

            i+=1
            j+=1


        #On fini de remplir la page
        bg = self.cget('bg')
        while(i<30):
            self.torrentsName[i+1].config(text="     ", background=bg)
            self.torrentsName[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=2)

            self.torrentsDesc[i+1].config(text="     ", background=bg)
            self.torrentsDesc[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=3)

            self.torrentsDate[i+1].config(text="     ", background=bg)
            self.torrentsDate[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=4)

            self.torrentsRatio[i+1].config(text="     ", background=bg)
            self.torrentsRatio[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=5)

            self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].config(text="Voir", state=DISABLED)
            self.torrentsGoTo[i+1].grid(row=i+2, column=6)

            i+=1


        if(page > 0):
            self.boutonPrev.config(command = lambda: self.dealString(chaine, page-1), state = NORMAL)
            self.boutonPrev.grid(row=32, column=2)
        else:
            self.boutonPrev.config(state = DISABLED)
            self.boutonPrev.grid(row=32, column=2)


        if(nbSplit>(page*nbPage)+nbPage):
            self.boutonSuiv.config(command = lambda: self.dealString(chaine, page+1), state = NORMAL)
            self.boutonSuiv.grid(row=32, column=3)
        else:
            self.boutonSuiv.config(state = DISABLED)
            self.boutonSuiv.grid(row=32, column=3)

    def deco(self):
        msg_a_envoyer = b"deconnect"
        connexion_avec_serveur.send(msg_a_envoyer)
        self.quit()




fenetre = Tk()
interface = Interface(fenetre)

interface.mainloop()
connexion_avec_serveur.close()
interface.destroy()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fenetre = Tk()
interface = Interface(fenetre)

interface.mainloop()
```

Looks like you're missing a `pack` here. Without it, the interface won't appear.

```
fenetre = Tk()
interface = Interface(fenetre)
interface.pack()
interface.mainloop()
```

Comment: That was that !
Thank you ! ;)

Strange that it worked before, though

Comment: @user3219238: it couldn't have. You must have been packing or grid'ing it somewhere.